# Formating a table with org mode

Tags: org-table

Can someone tell me how to format this sample table with org mode..

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  Total  | -> Header title center align ?
+-----|-----|-----|---------|
|  5  |  5  |  5  |   15    |
|  6  |  6  |  0  |   12    |
|-----|-----|-----|---------|
|            Total|   27    | -> merged cells = A B C ?
```

Also Print horizontal and vertical lines of the table.
Thk.

Comment: To the downvoter: please add a comment to explain *why* you downvoted. That is common courtesy in general, but it is particularly important for a new user: how are they going to learn the ropes if you don't explain what they did wrong?

Comment: 1. Vague question. 2. No sign of having read the manual or used web search.

Comment: 1) The format of your table is wrong: do `C-c | RET` to get a properly formatted, but empty, 5x2 table. 2) Org mode tables are simple: no merging of cells is done. 3) There are some formatting facilities for in-buffer display, but they are rudimentary: Org mode tables are aligned in terms of characters, not pixels. 4) As a corollary, you need a fixed width font to get proper alighment. 5)  Exported tables can use facilities of the backed (e.g. LaTeX/PDF or HTML) to get prettier formatting. 6) What kind of printing do you have in mind? Printing of the buffer or printing the exported output?

Comment: For the rudimentary formatting I mentioned above, see the `Column Width and Alignment` section of the Org mode manual: `C-h g(org)RET m Column Width RET`.

Comment: An answer related to merging cells is there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616460/merge-cells-in-org-mode-tables (As far as I know that answer is still valid.)

Comment: @Tobias: not really. You can use [table.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html) tables, as one answer does, but they are second-class citizens in Org mode: they are exported properly I believe, but you cannot do anything else with them (e.g. use a `#+TBLFM` on them): see the [Packages that Org cooperates with](https://orgmode.org/manual/Cooperation.html#Cooperation) section in the manual.